# Quiero crear archivos a partir de datos pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo mis datos en una columna de "orde" y quiero crear archivos cuyo nombre sean los 4 últimos caracteres de los valores en esa columna, mi código es:

```
for x in orde.index:
    nombre="C:/datos/codmat"+orde['CODMAT1'][x][-4:]+'.txt'
    fic.open(nombre,'w')
    fic.writelines("escribe cualquier cosa"\n")
fic.close()
```

me genera el siguiente error:

`'_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'open'`

¿Cómo puedo repararlo?
De antemano gracias

Answer (score 0):

Listo, solo me faltaba separar

En vez de

```
fic.open(nombre, 'w')
```

Debía escribir:

```
fic=open(nombre,'w')
```